# Online Google search Intelligent Quotient (IQ) test

Tags: search, testing

I would like to know if there any free online Google search Intelligent Quotient(IQ) test? Please share the link.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After doing a lot of searching, finally found an online Google search IQ test at http://devdebug.com/techhelp/google-search-iq-test/

The test contains 10 questions, I managed to score only 30%. Best of luck folks!